# is there any recursive way that I can remove the max number either from start or at the end?

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

I am checking if the list is sorted if it sorted than return false if not than remove the maxNumer in the list either from the start or the end not in the middle the middle is wanted but at end or the start no for example [1,2,3,4] expected false [9,1,2,3,4,6,22] // expected [1,2,3,4,6] thank you.

```
public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();

        list.add(9);
        list.add(2);
        list.add(3);
        list.add(4);
        list.add(5);
        list.add(22);
        var r = find132pattern(list);

        
    }

    
   public static boolean find132pattern(List<Integer> list) {

    int count = 0;
    String result = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
        int prev = i-1;
        int next = list.get(i);
        if(prev > -1){
            prev = list.get(i-1);
            if(prev > next){
                count+=1;
            }
        }
    }
    if(count > 0){
        result+="not sorted";
    }else {
        result+="sorted";
    }

    Integer start = 0;

    Integer end = list.size();

    Integer maxNum = Collections.max(list);

    Integer maxPos = list.indexOf(maxNum);

    
    if(result == "sorted"){
        return false;
    }else if(result == "not sorted" && maxPos == end || maxPos == start){
        list.remove(maxPos);
        find132pattern(list);
    }else {
        System.out.println(list);
    }
       
    
 return false;
}
    
}


// find an element
```

Comment: There's a lot in your code that is pretty confusing.

First, storing whether it's sorted or not a s a string is a bad idea - store that as a boolean. 

Is it your intention to only remove the max if the list is unsorted? If so, please edit that into your question.

Similarly, do we only want to remove it if it *is* the first or last element? Or are we guaranteed to be working with a list such that that is the case?

Can we have repeated elements in the list? What should we do with a list like, say, `1, 2, 2`?

Comment: Pleas add a failing test and debug-information you found so far

Comment: Continuing with the code review, using `+=` to append rather than `=` to overwrite is a weird phrasing - in this case it's equivalent because you're appending to an empty string, but it's confusing. It would actually be better to entirely separate that into an `isSorted` function (or just use a pre-existing one, like you do to get the max)

Comment: Please fix the  formatting of your code. (especially indention)

Comment: that's true, that's how I solved it last time exactly thank you genius.

Answer (score 0):

Store the index of the maximum element in your recursion and in the end, remove it.

```
List<Integer> RemoveBiggestFromList(List<Integer> list, int index, int maxIndex){
    if(index >= list.size()) {
        if(list.size() > 0) list.remove(maxIndex);
        return list;
    }
    else{
        if(list.get(index) > list.get(maxIndex)) maxIndex = index;
        return RemoveBiggestFromList(list, index + 1, maxIndex);
    }
}
```

Then, just do `list = RemoveBiggestFromList(list, 0, 0)`.

This is a recursive method to remove the biggest element wherever it is.